# Turn script into a function which extracts the div ID and places it inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Alright, so I've got this script which basically drains the thumbnails and streams from the twitch API/JSON.

```
$(function() {
    var i=0;
    var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams";
    var twitchData;
    $.getJSON(twitchApi, function(json) {
        twitchData = json.streams;

        setData()
    });

    function setData(){
        var j = twitchData.length > (i + 9)  ? (i + 9) : twitchData.length;
        for (; i < j; i++) {
            var streamGame = twitchData[i].game;
            var streamThumb = twitchData[i].preview.medium;
            var streamVideo = twitchData[i].channel.name;
            var img = $('<img style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" src="' + streamThumb + '"/>')
            $('#twitch').append(img);
            img.click(function(){
            $('#twitch iframe').remove()
            $('#twitch').append('<iframe style="width: 600px;" src="http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=' + streamVideo + '"></iframe>');
          });
        }
    }       

    $('#load').click(function() {
        setData();
    }); 
});
```

And I've got this code which basically filters the games. It works. When I click on League of Legends ( the `onClick` event is set on the #lol div, thus it works ), the div flushes and it returns with only League of Legends stream etcetera. But the code is veeeery messy. And I need a way how to make it cleaner ( without copy and pasting the script into each div ):

```
<div id="games" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <div id="lol">
            <p>League of Legends</p>
        </div>
        <div id="dota">
            <p>DOTA 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="hearthstone">
            <p>Hearthstone</p>
        </div>
        <div id="cs">
            <p>Counter-Strike</p>
    </div>
    <div id="cod">
        <p>Call of Duty</p>
     </div>
     <div id="minecraft">
        <p>Minecraft</p>
     </div>
     <div id="overwatch">
        <p>Overwatch</p>
     </div>
     <div id="xcom">
        <p>XCOM 2</p>
     </div>
     <div id="starcraft">
        <p>Starcraft</p>
     </div>

<script>

        $('#lol').click(function(){
            $('#twitch').children().fadeOut(500).promise().then(function() {
            $('#twitch').empty();
            var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=League%20of%20Legends";
            $.getJSON(twitchApi, function (json) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            var streamGame = json.streams[i].game;
            var streamThumb = json.streams[i].preview.medium;
            var streamVideo = json.streams[i].channel.name;
            $('#twitch').append('<img style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" src="' + streamThumb + '"></img>'); 
        }
    });
});
});


</script>


<script>
            $('#dota').click(function() {
                        $('#twitch').children().fadeOut(500).promise().then(function() {
                            $('#twitch').empty();
                            var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=Dota%202";
                            $.getJSON(twitchApi, function(json) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                                    var streamGame = json.streams[i].game;
                                    var streamThumb = json.streams[i].preview.medium;
                                    var streamVideo = json.streams[i].channel.name;
                                    $('#twitch').children().fadeIn(500).promise().then(function() {
                                            $('#twitch').append('<img style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" src="' +streamThumb + '"></img>');
                                        });
                                };
                            });
                        });
                    });
</script>

<script>
            $('#hearthstone').click(function(){
            $('#twitch').children().fadeOut(500).promise().then(function() {
            $('#twitch').empty();;
            var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=Hearthstone:%20Heroes%20of%20Warcraft";
            $.getJSON(twitchApi, function (json) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            var streamGame = json.streams[i].game;
            var streamThumb = json.streams[i].preview.medium;
            var streamVideo = json.streams[i].channel.name;
            $('#twitch').append('<img style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" src="' + streamThumb + '"></img>'); 
        }
    });
});});
</script>

<script>
            $('#cs').click(function(){
            $('#twitch').children().fadeOut(500).promise().then(function() {
            $('#twitch').empty();
            var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=Counter-Strike:%20Global%20Offensive";
            $.getJSON(twitchApi, function (json) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                var streamGame = json.streams[i].game;
            var streamThumb = json.streams[i].preview.medium;
            var streamVideo = json.streams[i].channel.name;
            $('#twitch').append('<img style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" src="' + streamThumb + '"></img>'); 
        }
    });
});});
</script>

    </div>
```

Can anyone help me out? I was thinking of making a function script which reads the div's paragraph and inserts it here:

```
var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=Hearthstone:%20Heroes%20of%20Warcraft";
```

So I have no idea how to make a `var gameName` which represents the div's paragraph. It needs to take what's inside the paragraph and place it here:

```
var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game="' + paragraph + ";
```

But honestly, I have no idea how to do it. The code works, but it's ugly and messy and I have no idea how to clean it up.

Comment: Go look at the jQuery documentation and do some practice. It is very easy to get the text contents of a DOM element using the syntax `$(selector).text()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you can setup a jQuery selector to respond to click events for each `div` inside the parent `div` with `id="games"`. This would then be placed inside your document ready function `$(function(){...});`. Once the event is triggered you can find the `p` element inside the div that was clicked and get the `text()` value which would be the name of the game.

```
$('div#games div').onclick(function(){
   var gameDiv = $(this); // Get which div was clicked here
   $('#twitch').children().fadeOut(500).promise().then(function() {
        $('#twitch').empty();
        var gameName = $(gameDiv).find('p').text().replace(' ', '%20');  // Get the game name
        var twitchApi = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=" + gameName;   // Build the URL here
        $.getJSON(twitchApi, function(json) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                var streamGame = json.streams[i].game;
                var streamThumb = json.streams[i].preview.medium;
                var streamVideo = json.streams[i].channel.name;
                $('#twitch').children().fadeIn(500).promise().then(function() {
                    $('#twitch').append('<img style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" src="' +streamThumb + '"></img>');
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Alright. So the thing I need to do know is basically.. Create a let's say.. game.js and implement it into my HTML <script src="js/game.js"> and I can go ahead and delete the numerous scripts which I've copy pasted? Because I've tried doing that and it isn't working.. Could you please explain what I'm doing wrong atm? The script you wrote looks as it is supposed to work. I'm on a code marathon, my brain is frozen and I'm unallowed to stop, so thanks a bunch for your help. @sbonkosky

Comment: @JohnDotHR Are you seeing an error of some sort when you try to include the script that way? Make sure that script tag is placed after the jQuery script tag.

Comment: Actually, yes I see one. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) .
But sadly, I think that I'll take a break, it has gotten so bad that I'm unable to look for brackets. I'd be thankful if you could do that for me. Ugh.  Thanks a lot for the help, once again. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JohnDotHR haha, np, think I got it, edited my answer.

Comment: Still the same error. :(

Comment: Able to fix it?

Comment: Can you explain how this code is better than what the author already has

Comment: @Quill It is supposed to replace all the scripts I have in my code with this one. So instead of specifying each script with a div it should autodetect the div.

Comment: @JohnDotHR Ok, think its fixed now.

Comment: @Quill He's trying to execute the script above every time someone clicks one of the game divs. His original code had the same logic repeated in multiple script tags which added an onclick handler to divs with specific ids. My code allows him to remove all the individual script tags and have the same functionality exist using only 1 onclick handler.